# Problemas com conexão SMTP no Uol Host

Tags: php, envio-de-email

Olá, Eu estou com um problema, não consigo enviar um e-mail autenticado via SMTP pelo Uol Host, o cliente possui uma hospedagem windows com PHP 5.2, e toda vez que eu tento enviar o e-mail aparece

> connect() failed

Atualmente eu estou usando a classe PHPMailer.

Comment: Poste o código que você utiliza pra enviar o e-mail e a parte onde registra as configurações, como SMTP, etc. (REMOVA ANTES QUALQUER INFORMAÇÃO QUE POSSA COMPROMETER SEU SISTEMA) Assim poderemos te ajudar

Comment: Coloque o código.